# Understanding variable share between recursion

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

I was doing this leetcode question:(https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/) in which I came up with this solution:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        if root is None:
            return None
        result = []

        if root.left is None and root.right is None:
            result.append(root.val)
            return result

        return self.traverse(root,result)


    def traverse(self,node,result):
        if node is None:
            return result

        result = self.traverse(node.left,result)
        result.append(node.val)
        result = self.traverse(node.right,result)

        return result
```

However I found out I actually don't need to store the results of recursion call in the variable and I can simply do this:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def inorderTraversal(self, root: TreeNode) -> List[int]:
        if root is None:
            return None
        result = []

        if root.left is None and root.right is None:
            result.append(root.val)
            return result

        return self.traverse(root,result)


    def traverse(self,node,result):
        if node is None:
            return result

        self.traverse(node.left,result)
        result.append(node.val)
        self.traverse(node.right,result)

        return result
```

My understanding was that in each recursion call, we are passing a reference to the result variable, not copying the result variable, so what is happening is that when the recursion call gets to the left most node, it appends the value and returns to its parent node, and since we had pass by reference, the result variable in parent node already has the leftmost node added to it, so it just adds the parent node to it and keep continuing on the recursion.
Is my understanding correct or is there something else going on?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your understanding is right.

Note: you are sharing the same code in both boxes.

Comment: Thanks
The code looks pretty similar, in the second box if you notice, I don't have result = self.traverse() instead I have only self.traverse(), or in other words, I am not explicitly storing the result in the result variable in the second box. But other than that they are pretty similar